# Adding arrow symbol in legend of CartoDB

Tags: carto, legend, html

I have been trying for some time now to get an arrow to appear in my legend in a CartoDB visualization - it is one of the simple visualization marker options along with the standard "ellipse", so I feel like it should thus be able to be added into a legend.

I've tried various ways tweaking the HTML for the legend, but have had no luck.

Has anyone successfully done this before in CartoDB?

Answer (score 2):

Using arrows is not an option defined in the current CSS of CartoDB, but bullets are defined [here](https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb/blob/master/vendor/assets/stylesheets/cartodb.css#L2312).

You'd need to add them from the image uploader (IMG button) for legends in order to use them. Unfortunately, there are no arrows in the icon sets available, so you'll need to use your own images.

[image: Custom legend: IMG button]